# Rank of Subgroup of Elliptic Curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, computer-algebra

I'm currently looking at two rational points $ p, q $ on an elliptic curve $E$ over $ \mathbb{Q} $.  SAGE tells me that $E$ has rank 5 and no torsion, and that $p$ and $q$ both have infinite order.  This is good news, but what I really want is for the subgroup of $E$ generated by $p, q $ to have rank 2.  Is there a way for me to check that $q$ is not a multiple of $p$ (or vice versa)?

I am extremely far from being an expert here, but somehow I have in my mind that the heights of the points will be useful.  The heights of $p$ and $q$ aren't integral multiples of each other (approximately 5.5 and 5.9 respectively).  Is this sufficient to show that they generate a subgroup of rank 2?

Comment: No, in general you need that the heights are not rational multiples of each other, not just integral (example being $4P=5Q$). Cremona gives a general process for point independence. Or, you can compute the regulator of the 2 points and see if it is nonzero. Sage has a trac ticket to fix this http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/ticket/9335 
$$ $$
You can use E.height_pairing_matrix([P,Q]) and take the determinant of that, and $P$ and $Q$ are independent when the determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, guys.  Indeed, the determinant of the height pairing matrix for those two points was nonzero, which is fantastic for me.

Comment: Aside: Would it not be much easier to check linear independency of $p$ and $q$ by reducing modulo some prime? From theory you know there are plenty (a positive proportion) of primes $\ell$ such that $p$ and $q$ generate a noncyclic subgroup of $E$ mod $\ell$, provided $p$ and $q$ are independent.